# Node cron job on GCP App Engine not working on weekends

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-app-engine, cron

I have a problem executing a cron job in node/express application using node-cron library. The application is deployed on Google Cloud App Engine.

I want to send automatic emails every day at 9 AM, but the cron only work from Monday to Friday.

Here is my code :

```
 cron.schedule("0 9 * * *", () => {
  sendEmails();
 },{
    scheduled: true,
    timezone: "Europe/Paris"
  });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

App Engine standard scales down to 0 instances if there is no traffic, if it happens that at 09:00 saturday/sunday there isn't any instance your Node cron job will not be executed.

---

Have you checked `cron.yaml`. Is this the preferred method for scheduling cron jobs in App Engine. The [sheduling job](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml?hl=en_US) would be the following:

```yaml
# cron.yaml
cron:
- description: "daily summary job"
  url: /tasks/sendemail
  schedule: every day 09:00

# end cron.yaml
```

With `schedule: every day 09:00` being the specified [custom interval](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml?hl=en_US#custom-interval)

Comment: /tasks/sendemail will be what exactly ?

Comment: This url will be trigger by App Engine, so in your Node application you need to have a handler for the URL.

Comment: Any example please ? or link ?

Comment: the links are in the answer

Comment: No I mean the  url: /tasks/sendemail , is that will be an API ?

Comment: your-app-engine-project.appspot.com/tasks/sendemail

Your node app has to have a handler for that url `tasks/sendemail` that includes the code that sends the email `sendsEmail()`.